How to find the largest isosceles trapezium with a set center inscribed in a closed polygon?
I need to find the largest (biggest area) isosceles trapezium inscribed inside a polygon, and the trapezium must have a set center.
The polygon is defined by an array of points in 2D. The polygon is closed and it can be convex or concave.
By isosceles trapezium I mean this shape.
Which is a quadrilateral with two parallel sides and one line of symmetry.
Center can mean many things, for this problem the center is the following

That is, the point where perpendicular line at the middle of the base meets the perpedincular line at the middle of the height.
The center of the trapezium must match an arbitrary point of the polygon. So for instance, if the polygon is the following, and the arbitrary point is the black dot:
The inscribed trapezium should be something like this:
My sample trapezium is probably not the largest one but lets assume it is. The parallel lines must be horizontal, so the following example is not valid:

I tried reading the algorithms to find out the biggest rectangle inscribed in a polygon, and adapting them, but they don't seem to be very flexible.

If I understood correctly, the trapezium doesn't need the rules you said. The trapezium can also be a square, and the rule that the angles must be equal is redundant, since I said that it must have a parallel line. Also, the polygon can also have any number of sides. I must have explained myself bad, I added some pictures to better explain it.

Are the parallel lines necessarily horizontal as in your pictures, or can it be any rotation? When you say largest, you mean what? Largest area?

@SimonGoater thank you for the question, I will edit my question in response. Yes, the parallel lines must be horizontal. Also, the diagonal lines can be upside down, so the acute angle is the upper one and viceversa. By largest, I mean the biggest area.

to help you find more information, you're looking for an "axis-aligned" fit. Also, what is "largest"? Bigggest area of the trapezoid?

But also, fairly importantly, what's your cutoff for "trapezoid" vs. "rectangle"? Because fitting a trapezoid with a 0.000000001 bias is about as easy as fitting a rectangle, and if we permit a short edge length of 0.0000000001 then we're just fitting a triangle: does that count? What's the angle requirement?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you for the heads up on the "axis-aligned". I already specified that largest means biggest are in the post.
I don't understand why fitting a trapezoid with a 0.0000001 bias is about as easy as fitting a rectangle, because I don't know what "bias" means in this context. Yes, a trapezoid with a short edge of 0.00000001 is also valid. The angle requirement is for the angles that meet across the horizontal lines to be equal, basically, the upper angles must be the same, and the lower angles must be the same. I think specified when I said it has one parallel line.

This problem gets a lot easier if you:

Rotate it by 90 degrees; and
Fold it in half

So that this:

Becomes this:

Now, you're only concerned with the maximum height available at every x position, and you only have to find the top line of the best half-trapezoid that fits underneath that envelop:

The envelope is easy to calculate as a piecewise function just by finding the original line segment with the minimum height at every x position.
To find the top line of the best trapezoid, you can try every pair of segments between each pair of zero crossings, and find the best top line that connects those spans.

Awesome origami solution!

Thank you for the reply. I am really having troubles to understand your solution, could you explain it in another way? Also, does that solution take into account that the trapezoid must be centered in an arbitrary point? I can't tell because I don't understand it.
